# Mostrar solamente una parte del Iframe

Tags: html, string, iframe

Quiero mostrar, del iframe que contiene la página, sólo la parte donde está el string aleatorio generado por ésta.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=12&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new"/>
```

Tengo el código, pero no sé cómo mostrar esa parte y ocultar todo lo demás. 
Sólo quiero que se vea el string que se genera en la página.

Espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Hola Jenio, a que "String" te refieres

Comment: Que yo sepa, el sitio que llamas desde un iframe no lo puedes modificar

Comment: Entra en la pagina, y te sale un string con letras y/o numeros, ese string.

Answer (score 1):

Por razones de seguridad no es posible manipular los sitios que se muestran en iframes desde el sitio principal, sin embargo puedes hacer algunos trucos como usar divs, desplazar el iframe algunos pixeles arriba e izquierda, y ocultar todo lo demás:

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 30px; width: 200px">
    <iframe src="https://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&amp;len=12&amp;digits=on&amp;upperalpha=on&amp;loweralpha=on&amp;unique=on&amp;format=html&amp;rnd=new" height="300" style="position: relative; top: -220px; left: -20px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Sin embargo esto no impide que el iframe siga funcionando como tal, permitiendo al usuario desplazar el contenido con su mouse, para cubrir eso puedes poner un div con `opacity: 0`, pero eso ya es complicar algo que en principio se ve simple.

Te sugiero que utilices su API o en su defecto crear tu propio script generador de strings aleatorios.

Answer (score 0):

Como tal, tu iframe ya se está mostrando, lo único que haría falta sería definir el ancho y alto que este debe ocupar en tu página.
Por otro lado, deberías probar con la etiqueta `frame`, dado que `iframe` actualmente es obsoleta y su seguridad nula.

Comment: <iframe width="200px" height="100px" position="relative" src="https://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=12&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new"/>
  
  Tengo esto, pero solo se muestra el top, y las barras de desplazamiento.

Comment: Bueno primero, que todo la etiqueta iframe permite incorporar una pagina dentro de otra, es decir toma o abarca toda una página web externa dentro de tu propia página, con esto en mente la etiqueta iframe **no toma pedasos de una pagina web**, bueno almenos que la pagina este diseñado de esta forma y segundo si deseas eliminar las barras de desplazamiento debes de agregar lo siguiente al tag de apertura del iframe scrolling="no"